# why do we need React forwardRef if we can simple pass the created ref in props?

Tags: reactjs, react-ref, react-forwardref

The correct way of passing refs to child components as per react documentation is like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
  }, []);
  return <input type="text" ref={ref} />;
});

export default function App() {
  const inputRef = React.createRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <Input ref={inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if i try to pass the created ref as a normal prop in any other name then 'ref', this also works as expected.

```
import React from 'react';

const Input = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  return <input type="text" ref={props.inputRef} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const inputRef = React.createRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <Input inputRef={inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So the question is, is forwardRef doing something special which we cannot achieve with normal props?

Comment: both your examples are wrong and need to use `useRef`, search for createRef vs useRef. The rest is explained in the dup answer

Comment: The more interesting question is why `ref` is a reserved word which cannot become a prop unless component is wrapped with awkward `forwardRef`

Answer (score 12):

It is not necessary to use `forwardRef`, as per the official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

> Ref forwarding is a technique for automatically passing a ref through a component to one of its children. This is typically not necessary for most components in the application. However, it can be useful for some kinds of components, especially in reusable component libraries. The most common scenarios are described below.

You can do something similar by passing the `ref` with another prop name like `divRef`. But if you will pass ref as `ref` prop, then `React will not allow that` and **will not associate ref with DOM element** and will show warning [image: warning]

If you want to make your element as natural like other elements and refer them
with `ref` using `ref` prop keyword, then it is mandatory to `forwardRef`, otherwise not.