I get a ts error when I try to access .current saying current doesn't exist but in fact it does and I can access it,
I'm trying to get rid of the error occurring when im accessing .current from mainContainer passed from the App component, the error says

Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: unknown) => void) | MutableRefObject'.
Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: unknown) => void'.ts(2339)
any

But it actually exists and I can access it.
//parent App component

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.tsx"
import app from "./App.module.css"
import { useRef } from "react"

function App() {
  const mainContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <div id={app.mainContainer} ref={mainContainer}>
        <button className="nav-btn" id="open-nav-btn">Menu</button>
        <Navbar ref={ mainContainer } />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App





//child component
import  "./navbar.css"
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
import { forwardRef, useRef } from "react";
import { ExpoScaleEase } from "gsap/EasePack";
gsap.registerPlugin(useGSAP,ExpoScaleEase);


const Navbar = forwardRef(function Navbar( props , ref ) {
  const navContainer = useRef(null);
  const mainContainer = ref;
  
  const { contextSafe } = useGSAP({ scope: navContainer });

  const closeNav = contextSafe(() => {

  const duration : number = 0.4;

  if(mainContainer && navContainer){
    
    gsap.set(
      mainContainer.current,
      {
        overflow: "auto",
      });  
    
    gsap.to(
      navContainer.current,
      {
        opacity: 0,
        ease: "power2.in",
        duration: duration
      }
    );
  
    gsap.set(
      navContainer.current,
      {
        clipPath: "inset(100% 0% 0% 0%)",
        delay: duration   
      }
    );
  
    gsap.set(
      navContainer.current,
      {
        display: "none",
        delay: duration  
      },
    );
    
      gsap.set(
        navContainer.current,
        {
          display: "none",
          delay: duration  
        }
      );
  }

});

  
  return (
     <div id="nav-container" ref={navContainer}>
        <button className="nav-btn" id="close-nav-btn" onClick={closeNav}>Close</button>
        <div className="nav-wrapper">
          <nav>
            <ul className="nav-pages">
              <li>HOME</li>
              <li>ABOUT</li>
              <li>CONTACT</li>
              <li>PROJECTS</li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            <ul className="nav-socials">
              <li>Instagram</li>
              <li>Linkedin</li>
              <li>Github</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <p>Mirko Bellopede <br /> Full stack web developer Portfolio 2024 ©</p>
        </div>
      </div>

  )
});


export default Navbar


I've already tried to specify the type as refobj<HTMLDivElement> with no results, I assume is something type related, like it doesn't know his type and assume that .current doesn't exist on that generic type.
I red from the doc that forwardRef is for make accessible the ref from the component to the parent, but i also red the reverse in other sources.
Could someone make an example of code to access the ref of an element from the app component to the child component?

Here the child's (Navbar) DOM node is being exposed (forwardRef) to the parent (App), not the other way. See https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef#exposing-a-dom-node-to-the-parent-component. mainContainer.current check need to happen in the parent component (App).

Thanks for the answer, is there a way to pass the ref from the parent to the child and use  it? I want to use the reference from the app component of "main-container" in the child component.

Theoretically you can pass the parent ref as prop to the child, but React won't allow to do so. It breaks the pure function paradigm in the child component, as it might change the DOM node of parent, i.e., something that exists outside of its scope. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70150360. I suggest to do all the checks/validation in the parent, and pass the result as prop to the child.
